# JPA + EclipseLink - Lazy Loading com EntityManager fechada

Tags: java, jpa, jdbc, lazy-loading, eclipse-link

Estou usando o EclipseLink como provider JPA em um projeto Java SE. Já configurei corretamente o weaving para permitir o Lazy Loading.

Ao contrário do Hibernate (que lança LazyInitializationException), o EclipseLink consegue obter o proxy de um relacionamento LAZY, mesmo com o EntityManager fechado. Para executar essa query, ele obtém uma nova conexão do pool.

Alguém sabe se existe alguma configuração que desabilita ou altera o comportamento dessa funcionalidade? Eu preciso receber um valor null ou uma exceção ao tentar acessar um atributo não carregado, assim como o Hibernate faz.

Exemplo:

```
List<Cliente> clientes = entityManager.createQuery("from Cliente c", Cliente.class).getResultList();
entityManager.close(); // fechando o EntityManager

for (Cliente cliente : clientes) {
    cliente.getEndereco(); // Aqui o EclipseLink executa uma query para trazer o relacionamento.
}
```

Obrigado.

Comment: Rodolpho, não tenho muita experiência com o Eclipselink, mas não é justamente o weaving que cria o proxy para relacionamentos lazy?
Existem algumas properties relacionadas ao comportamento de lazy load aqui: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Performance/Weaving/Disabling_Weaving_with_Persistence_Unit_Properties, talvez alguma lhe ajude.